# How to get form data value from html and show on other html page

Tags: html, forms

I am working on a html page with an input bar. How can I get the form data from this page to another html page with a iframe? Because I need to embed the search result from other site but I want to show on my site new page. I just guess should use iframe. But I don't know how to get data and add in page address field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options here:

1) If your form uses GET method, then all the text data from the form will be passed to next page (which is set up as an "action" attribute of the form) in URL (like www.example.com/?name=John&lastname=Doe). After that, you can extract data from this URL using code from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) and put it inside HTML element using Javascript as well like it is done [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)

2) Whatever server language you use, you can get query variables from there and put them to the page before sending it to the client. In case of PHP, check [this](https://napitwptech.com/tutorial/displaying-form-value-using-php/) example. NB: don't forget about security.

3) You can temporarily store text in localStorage API of the browser. Simply set the value before submitting the form and then get it on the next page.

iFrame would be inefficient and not needed here.